# Draw a cascade of walls

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

In a render engine, I want to build a random cascade of walls. Each wall has a unique angle between each other, and the coordinate of the wall is its center-point. For now, each wall has the same width $w$. If it is easy to create difference size-walls, that would be great too.

Here is an illustration what I want to do:

[image]

After calculated the parameters, the drawing procedure would be like this:

- Draw wall 1 with width $w$ at coordinate $P_1$ with angle $a_0$
- Draw wall 2 with width $w$ at coordinate $P_2$ with angle $a_1$
- Draw wall 3 with width $w$ at coordinate $P_3$ with angle $a_2$

**What I have done so far**

If wall X is orthogonal to the world's y-axis, and the angle between wall X and wall Y is $a$, then the vector is like this:

[image]

$\Delta x = \frac{w}{2} \cdot sin(a - 90^{\circ}) + \frac{w}{2}$

$\Delta y = \frac{w}{2} \cdot cos(a - 90^{\circ})$^

$\vec{v} = (\Delta x, \Delta y)$

This works so far.

Now I need to address 2 more issues:

1. The first wall should be located arbitary in the room
2. Find a procedure to find the center-points of all walls

**Next step**

Given are all angles $a_1$, $a_2$, ... 
Given are are coordinate $(x_0, y_0)$ and Angle $a_0$ of first wall.

Searched are coordinates of the walls $P_2$, $P_2$, ...

After finding the offset between wall X and wall Y, I probably would need to apply an rotation matrix with all previous angles. But that doesn't work.

Here is an example what I tried:

Wall 1 is still orthogonal in the room. (Has to be addressed later):

$a_0 = 0$

$P_1 = (0,0)$

Apply previously mentioned working method for vector between $P_1$ and $P_2$:

$m_x = \Delta x (P1 to P2) = \frac{w}{2} \cdot sin(a_2 - 90^{\circ}) + \frac{w}{2}$

$m_y = \Delta y (P1 to P2) = \frac{w}{2} \cdot cos(a_2 - 90^{\circ})$

$\vec{m} = (m_x, m_y)$

Finding the vector between $P_2$ and $P_3$:

$n_x = \Delta x (P2 to P3) = \frac{w}{2} \cdot sin(a_2 - 90^{\circ}) + \frac{w}{2}$

$n_y = \Delta y (P2 to P3) = \frac{w}{2} \cdot cos(a_2 - 90^{\circ})$

$\vec{n} = (n_x, n_y)$

Apply rotation matrix to that vector because wall 2 is not orthogonal in the room:

$r_x = n_x \cdot cos(a_0 + a_1) - n_y \cdot sin(a_0 + a_1)$

$r_y = n_x \cdot sin(a_0 + a_1) + n_y \cdot cos(a_0 + a_1)$

$\vec{r} = (r_x, r_y)$

The parameters for drawing wall 3 are:

- Angle = $a_0 + a_1 + a_2$
- Position = $P_1 + \vec{m} + \vec{r}$

However, the result is similar to that:

[image]

I am trying to figure out this formula since a few days, and don't find a solution. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct procedure to find $P_i$ for given $a_i$ , including the fact that wall 1 can have an arbitary position and angle in the room? A wonderful would be to allow individual $w_i$ for each wall.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see every wall as a vector of lenght $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered in the origin. Then the coordinates of the edge of the last wall would be just the sum of the vectors. From there should be easy fo find the coordinates of the center.

Comment: @mrprottolo Thank you for this idea. This is probably making it much easier. I tried to follow that approach and have now following procedure: http://pastebin.com/sXiSLXZr . I determinate the end of the vector, which is the start of the vector of the next wall. The "center" of each vector is the wall-center. Each wall has a absolute rotation of sum(a0+a1+...). It still doesn't work, as the walls are now not connected at all. But the procedure looks very clean and logical to me.

Comment: the problem might be that when you sum $w/2 \cos a$, you have to use as $a$ the sum of all the angle up to that step, not just the angle you want to sum. That's because you want to move from the end of the previous wall following the new slope, that's the sum of all the previous slopes.

Comment: sorry, I have a few problems understanding your reply. Where do I sum $w/2 cos a$ ? I sum the angles. Can you show me a corrected formula, please? It is easier to understand for me then.

Comment: I have tried this now, as I probably understood one problem: http://pastebin.com/YjFCrb35 . But it still does not work. For 90° it works, but for 130° not.

Comment: you should do something like "center_y = start_y + (w/2) * sin(sum_a)"